ROS2 Iron in Docker unable to locate package ros-iron-controller-manager
As a part of a larger project, I'm trying to install packages for ROS Iron in a Docker container. Am running this on arm64.
Minimal Dockerfile:
FROM ros:iron

RUN apt update

RUN rosdep install ros-iron-controller-manager

Docker build command:
docker build -t ros_iron_docker_test .

Error:
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource ros-iron-controller-manager

Using apt install ros-iron-controller-manager also results in E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-controller-manager
https://superuser.com/questions/1849157/cant-install-apt-package-in-docker-while-can-install-in-regular-shell I believe this post may be related, but I can't confirm and wanted to get this to an audience more experienced with ROS.
